# How to add Strings from a Char Array to a String in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a program that generates random words from Katakana (Japanese syllables).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

char* word;
char *kata[] = {"ア", "イ", "ウ", "エ", "オ", "カ", "キ", "ク", "ケ", "コ", "サ", "シ", "ス","セ","ソ","タ","チ","ツ","テ","ト","ナ","ニ","ヌ",
"ネ","ノ","ハ","ヒ","フ","ヘ","ホ","マ","ミ","ム","メ","モ","ヤ","ユ","ヨ","ラ","リ","ル","レ","ロ","ワ","ヲ","ン","ガ","ギ",
"グ","ゲ","ゴ","ザ","ジ","ズ","ゼ","ゾ","ダ","ヂ","ヅ","デ","ド","バ","ビ","ブ","ベ","ボ","パ","ピ","プ","ペ","ポ","ャ","ュ",
"ョ","ヴ","ァ","ィ","ゥ","ェ","ォ"};
int x = 0;

void generator (int length) {
      for (int z=0; z<length; z++) {
        x = rand() % sizeof(*kata);
        concat(word,kata[x]);
      }
}

int main (void) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    int length = rand() % 5 + 2;
    generator(length);
    puts(word);
}
```

***word*** is the String that I want to get printed, and ***kata*** is a Char Array containing Katakana. However, if I don't include the "*" to make the array an String array, C complains that there are multiple characters in a char. The rest of the code works fine in my testing.

I'm using BoUoW which has a full Ubuntu environment on Windows, so I don't think that's the problem, but rather how I'm putting the String array into the String.

I've done a similar program in Java in about an hour and this has taken me much longer. Although that's probably because I'm new to C.

Comment: 1) `concat` is not defined. 2) `word` is `NULL`. 3) `sizeof(*kata)` isn't number of elements.

Comment: Add warning and error when you compile will allow you (and us) to save lot of time

Comment: Compilers might not support having non-ascii characters in the source file

Comment: C does not have a string type. And from your question, you are in urgent need to learn the basics first, i.e. pointers, arrays, etc. The `*` does **not** make "an array a string array", thats a vital missconception. And there is no "Ubuntu environment" on Windows!

Comment: @Olaf I think BoUoW is Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Which actually creates a Linux environment. Windows part is irrelevant thoough.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: 1) Ubuntu is not a synonym for Linux. 2) That is **not** a "Linux environemtn", but a compatibility layer similar to Wine. No one would say Wine is Windows! How the bash is relevant here is not clear. But it hints even more it is not really Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of check should be added (overflow on word for example)
The number of element on kata is the `sizeof` kata / `sizeof` an element you can do a macro `countof`
`strcat` is the function you need.

The idea is something like

```
char *kata[] = {"ア", "イ", "ウ", "エ", "オ", "カ", "キ", "ク", "ケ", "コ", "サ", "シ", "ス","セ","ソ","タ","チ","ツ","テ","ト","ナ","ニ","ヌ
",
    "ネ","ノ","ハ","ヒ","フ","ヘ","ホ","マ","ミ","ム","メ","モ","ヤ","ユ","ヨ","ラ","リ","ル","レ","ロ","ワ","ヲ","ン","ガ","ギ",
    "グ","ゲ","ゴ","ザ","ジ","ズ","ゼ","ゾ","ダ","ヂ","ヅ","デ","ド","バ","ビ","ブ","ベ","ボ","パ","ピ","プ","ペ","ポ","ャ","ュ",
    "ョ","ヴ","ァ","ィ","ゥ","ェ","ォ"};
int x = 0;

static void generator (int nb, char *word, size_t n) {
    word[0] = '\0';
    while (nb-- > 0) {
        x = rand() % (sizeof(kata) / sizeof(char*));
        strcat(word, kata[x]);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    char word[64];
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    int nb = rand() % 5 + 2;
    generator(nb, word, sizeof(word));
    puts(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest, that you should also add `word[0] = '\0';` as the first line of generator. I agree it will work fine the first time. But generator seems like a function that will be called multiple times.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya in that case I think word should be a param of the generator function.

Comment: Yes, or it could be something like generate and print. Which is also what is there in the question. He might want to print multiple strings of random length.

Comment: I'm quite new to C so I don't understand the pointers and strings thing yet, but this works well, thank you. I have a lot more studying to do over the summer.

Answer (score 0):

Which book are you reading? The reason I ask is that you've encountered a series of categorical errors regarding the fundamentals of C which people who read *good books* don't usually encounter. I can recommend K&R2E to someone who's already experienced programming from another language.

> ***word*** is the String ...

Not in the code you've shown us, no... `word` contains a null pointer, and in your code you're *assigning into* that null pointer. Bad news :(

Stop confusing the concept of strings (which are a category of values) with pointers (which are a category of types).

A **string** is a sequence of character values that terminates at the first `'\0'`. That's a value. Strings are stored within arrays; an array is a category of type.

A **pointer** denotes a type which has values that point at/into arrays (which might or might not contain a string), functions or at *nothing* (which are null pointers).

> ... ***kata*** is a Char Array containing Katakana ...

Again, this isn't the case. `kata` is an array of `char *`. `char *` is not a *character type*; it's a *character pointer type*!

> However, if I don't include the "*" to make the array an String array, C complains that there are multiple characters in a char.

I'm not sure what you expect. Since the type of a string literal expression such as `"ア"` is a `char[n]` (character array type) which gets converted to a `char *` (character pointer type) with a value pointing at the first character, and you store multiple of those in an array, the type of your array needs to be `char *[m]`. The `*` is ***necessary!*** I don't see a problem here.

---

I do see other problems, however. Firstly, `concat` isn't defined. You've not asked a question about this, so here's the definition I'll use to fill in the blanks:

```
void concat(char *dest, char *src) {
    strcat(dest, src); // `strcat` is from `<string.h>`
}
```

`sizeof(*kata)` retrieves the size of a `char *`, which is commonly four or eight... so `rand() % sizeof(*kata)` will equate to `rand() % 4` or `rand % 8` on common systems. Perhaps you meant `rand() % (sizeof kata / sizeof *kata)`. More on that later...

As I mentioned earlier, `word` is a *null pointer* and you can't assign into such a pointer. You need to *make it point at something*. You can do this by:

- <strike>Using the `&`address-of operator on a variable.</strike> I assume this isn't suitable for you, as you'll want your pointer to point at a sequence of more than one object, but this is helpful to explain anyway. For example:

  ```
  int x;
  int *pointer_to_x = &x;
  ```
- Declaring an array, and using the identifier of the array, possibly in conjunction with the `+` addition operator to point at an element in the array. For example:

  ```
  int array[42];
  int *pointer_to_first = array + 0;
  int *pointer_to_second = array + 1;
  ```
- Calling `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc` or some other function that returns a pointer to a suitably sized object. For example:

  ```
  int *pointer_to_whatever = malloc(42 * sizeof *pointer_to_whatever);
  // Remember to free(pointer_to_whatever) ONCE when you're done with it
  ```

`int` isn't really appropriate for storing array indexes or lengths; you're better off using `size_t` as that *doesn't have negative values* which doesn't just eliminate some bugs, but also makes your code a little more efficient.

`rand() % sizeof(*kata)` isn't very *random*.

In fact, it's quite *predictable*. By reseeding with the same seed, another program can reproduce that exact sequence. By iterating on seeds, starting with `seed = time(NULL)` and moving backwards in time, it's easy enough to prove that this is no less *predictable* than a single `int` value, despite the fact that it is in fact multiple *character* values.

Additionally, `rand` tends to introduce biases, *especially* when you use the `%` operator to reduce it. You need to remove the bias. You could do this by first assigning your random number to a `double`, then dividing it by `RAND_MAX + 1.0` like so:

```
double rand_double(void) {
    return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

With this function returning a value between `0.0` and `1.0` (excluding `1.0`), you should be able to use `rand_double() * (sizeof kata / sizeof *kata)` for example, and this will be *better*... but the bias is *still* there; it's just reduced. To eliminate the bias, you need to consider that `rand` returns a sequence of values, each of which lie within `[0..RAND_MAX]`, and that your range *doesn't divide evenly* into that range; the *remainder* of the division is a huge part of your *bias*. You need to take the range, and truncate it down to something that *does divide evenly*! That is, make a function that wraps `rand` and discards values greater than `RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % (sizeof kata / sizeof *kata))`... I've described (and solved) this problem [in a solution I posted on gist](https://gist.github.com/Sebbyastian/3888f468412dbe37e7c4), so for your convenience here's an adaptation of that code:

```
unsigned int rand_range(unsigned int ceiling) {
    int n;
    do {
        n = rand();
    } while (RAND_MAX - n <= RAND_MAX % ceiling);
    return n % ceiling;
}
```

This is *better again*, but **you won't want to use *anything `rand`-derived* for security purposes**, so *don't use this for passwords*! This is because of the attack described earlier, where people can *go back in time* by *reseeding* to produce values previously generated. Use a [cryptographically secure random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) for that.

Comment: K&R 2nd edition was bad even back in 1990. Today it is hopelessly outdated and should not be used for any purpose - particularly not for learning.

Comment: I haven't picked up a book yet, I've only been relying on video tutorials and Stackoverflow. As I wrote the program I was learning the language. I **will** be getting a book to study from because I need desperately to understand pointers. Coming from Java, C and its rules seem a bit overcomplicated, but I will try to be open-minded. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @TheBitStick You can't learn C by mashing your face on a keyboard like you can learn Java. This is because you can't rely upon an implementation to *crash* when you've overflowed an array, raced threads, double-freed, etc. Though these behaviours will commonly cause crashes, sometimes they go unnoticed for a *long* time and turn into *software vulnerabilities*. **Do not continue until you have a decent quality book (such as K&R2E)!** Lundin: You seem to share an unpopular opinion, one which I think you should discuss on Freenodes ##C chatroom as I believe you might need debugging.

Comment: @Lundin Nonetheless, your suggestion leads the OP in no helpful direction as you've not provided an alternative. Perhaps you could enlighten us with an even more scholarly-approved suggestion.

Comment: @Seb It is not an unpopular opinion. It is an opinion shared by everyone who 1) is a veteran C programmer, 2) has read K&R and 3) haven't been living under a rock during the past 30 years. The reasons people recommend K&R is nostalgia and nothing else. I have never heard a rational argument about what's good about the book. It is not the 1980s any longer, we have an ISO standard.

Comment: @Seb Unfortunately there are not a lot of decent C books. I don't know any good ones that's directed to beginners. I would probably recommend reading through the comp.lang.c FAQ or the [SO C FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) rather than reading books, because these FAQs are of much higher quality because of peer review. You don't get away with writing a crappy C answer on SO, but you get away with writing a crappy C book any day of the year, apparently.

Comment: @Lundin I noticed the OP here mentioned they have some programming experience, which most certainly makes K&R2E more appropriate for them than a *beginner*. What credentials do you have that qualify you to judge the efficacy of educational resources? Are you a professor or a peer reviewer for an educational institution? If so, I'd love to know, how would you improve upon K&R2E?